# Is it possible / how to overload function call operator in Scala?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading

I read, that in Scala you can overload any operator, not as in Groovy. But I saw no any example how to overload function call.

Is it possible / how to overload function call operator in Scala?

I know that "there is no operators in Scala", but despite this, I need to do what I would name that.

Comment: You can overload methods, including methods with names like `+()` and `*()`, which makes it look like operator overloading. And you can overload the `apply()` method, which makes it look a function call overload. But I don't believe it is possible to overload a true function, which is, essentially, a value, and values can't take on 2 different meanings.

Answer (score 3):

function call is spelled `apply`.  Any object which has a method named `apply` overloads function call.

```
class Functionish(val int: Int, val str: String) {
  def apply(i: Int): Int = i + int
  def apply(s: String): String = s + str + s
}

val f = new Functionish(42, "hello")

println(f(4))
println(f("George, "))
```

prints

```
46
George, helloGeorge,
```

Of note: case class companion objects overload `apply`.  This is why you can create a case class instance with

```
val instance = CaseClass(foo, bar, baz)
```

instead of

```
val instance = new CaseClass(foo, bar, baz)
```

Comment: [Scala Language Specification Chapter 6 *Expressions* Section 6 *Function Applications*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications) Paragraph 5: "If `f` has some value type, the application is taken to be equivalent to `f.apply(e1, …, em1)`, i.e. the application of an `apply` method defined by `f`. The value `f` is applicable to the given arguments if `f.apply` is applicable." It is also explained in any introductory Scala tutorial, course, or book, and as part of [the `FunctionN` traits](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every "callable" object is called via `apply` method:

```
scala> def foo(i: Int) = i * i
foo: (i: Int)Int

scala> val f = foo _
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(42)
res2: Int = 1764

scala> f.apply(42)
res3: Int = 1764
```

Is that what are you looking for?